# Why are style assignments performed immediately after creation not animated?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css

Opening [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWnnH/2/) on Webkit will show what I'm talking about.

How can I specify an element's style when it is first specified, and then its final state?

It should be possible to specify a single step animation fully this way (without having to start using @keyframes) but it seems like there is a lot of implementation specific strangeness I must deal with at this point. Note how in Firefox no animation is performed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be the same issue as described here: [CSS3 transitions to dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969817/css3-transitions-to-dynamically-created-elements)

so

```
$("#one").on('click',function(){
    var word = $("<div style='opacity: 0; height:0'>word</div>");
    $('body').prepend(word); 
    window.getComputedStyle(word[0]).getPropertyValue("top");
    word.css({height: 100, opacity: 1});
});
```

also works in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/wWnnH/3/

Comment: careful with too much getComputedStyle, though. it's fairly expensive as it has to update the styles for the whole page. if you do this a lot, it will stutter the UI. You can batch it for performance: create all your objects, then getComputedStyle *once*, then set all your updates.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use jQuery.animate()

```
word.animate({height: 100, opacity: 1}, 5000);
```

Will work without the CSS, and on both webkit and mozilla. Although this defeats the purpose of trying to use CSS3 I guess.

Comment: This creates a jerky, unsynchronized and bad looking animation where it fades in, then starts moving. Also, the element continues to look cut off (if it started out cut off due to height setting) for the duration of the animation.

Comment: I should add that some of those side effects may be caused by the fact that I tested it without turning off the transition durations, which will cause the transitions to be applied for each change that jQuery sets. This is obviously no good so I'll be back to report on the performance of jQuery animate() when I get around to properly testing it.

Comment: This solution works wonderfully in IE9 (the one browser that excels at animating with jQuery). It looks too good to be true, really.